# Query execution count for Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, rdbms

On our Prod Database which is based on Oracle, I want to see the number of queries which get fired.

The reasoning behind is that we want to see the number of network calls we make and the impact firewall could make if we move it to a cloud system.

```
select sum(EXECUTIONS)
from v$sql
where last_active_time >= trunc(sysdate)-2 
and (parsing_schema_name like '%\_RW%' escape '\' or parsing_schema_name = 'TEMP_USER')   
and module not in ('DBMS_SCHEDULER') 
and sql_text not like '%v$sql%';
```

Above query doesn't seem very reliable due to SQLs being pushed out of memory which is what the above one returns.

Is there any way to get the number of calls we make on our Oracle DB from the database itself? Logging from all the applications is not a feasible option at the moment.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using an Enterprise database?  Do you have AWR?

Comment: We are using enterprise DB and we do have AWR.

Comment: Thanks instanceOfObject.  Good to hear.  I wonder if the AWR views might get at your goal -- for example `DBA_HIST_SQLSTAT` includes many data about sql workload (such as `EXECUTIONS_DELTA`) on a recent and cumulative basis, per schema per sql statement.  Loads, cpu, etc is there and can `sum`med, etc and tied to a `parsing_schema_name`.   The workload can be viewed at different times of day by selecting different `DBA_HIST_SNAPSHOT`s.  I wondered if this is the kind of data you were looking for?

Comment: Try your query with v$sqlstats.  This has better retention than v$sql, even after the cursor has been aged out of the shared pool.

Comment: Thanks alexgibbs/sandman. That's the kind of data I am looking for. Though I also wanted to group it by the module which is only available in DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESS_HISTORY, but I see a lot lesser count than it should be in that table.

Sample query I ran: select count(*), trunc(sample_time) from DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESS_HISTORY where trunc(sample_time) > sysdate - 10 group by trunc(sample_time);

Answer (score 1):

> "we want to see the number of network calls we make and the impact firewall could make if we move it to a cloud system"

The number of SQL statements executed is only tangentially related to the amount of network traffic. Compare the impact of `select * from dual` with `select * from humongous_table`.

A better approach might be to talk with your network admin and see what they can tell you about the traffic your applications generate. Alternatively download [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) and see for yourself (providing your security team is cool with that).

Answer (score 0):

Just to add some information on V$SQL views:

**V$SQLAREA** has the lowest retention, and shows the current SQL in memory, parsed, and ready for execution.

**V$SQL** has better retention, and is updated every 5 seconds after query execution.

**V$SQLSTATS** has the best retention, and retains SQL even after the cursor has been aged out of the shared pool.

You don't want to run these queries too often on busy production databases, as they can add to shared pool fragmentation.